# append() method loops on all elements of a list in python

Tags: python, append, nodes, namedtuple

I'am using namedtuples object to create Nodes and Graphs to represent a network. The goal is to allocate resources of a main network, referred to as network, to smaller networks, referred to as requests.

A request is considered fulfilled when all its node are associated to a network node and the "shape" of the request is kept, as shown on image below. Request is represented in red

[Example of fulfilled request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVMLd.png)

Nodes items are built as follow :
Node = namedtuple('Node', 'name val alloc', defaults=[[]])

Graphs items are built as follow :
Graph = namedtuple('Graph', 'nodes edges', defaults=[[], []])

Here are the network and request from the image, built in Python

```
a = Node('a', 10)
b = Node('b', 6)
c = Node('c', 5)
    
Vnode = namedtuple('Vnode', 'name val')
    
x1 = Vnode('x1', 3)
y1 = Vnode('y1', 4)

Graph = namedtuple('Graph', 'nodes edges', defaults=[[], []])

vne = Graph([a, b, c])
```

I tried to isolate the code that doesn't work as intended, here it is :

```
def allocate(node, node_vnf, visited, visited_vnf, to_visit, to_visit_vnf):

    # node_vnf = node to place;
    # to_visit = network nodes that haven't been visited;
    # to_visit_vnf : request nodes that haven't been visited

    if node_vnf.val <= node.val and node_vnf not in visited_vnf and node not in visited:  # Are there enough resources free on the node ?
        
        node.alloc.append(node_vnf) # We had the request node to the network node attribute alloc
        
        node = node._replace(val=(node.val-node_vnf.val)) # change the value of network node 
        visited_vnf.append(node_vnf)
        visited.append(node)

        return node
    else:
        return node
```

In the function above, append() applied to node.alloc, attribute alloc of Node object node, loops on all nodes of the network instead of just adding node_vnf at the end of node.alloc.

Does anyone have an idea, on why append() method does work as intended ? I tried using insert() too, but it acts the same.

Please let me know if any information on the subject is missing or isn't clear.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: If `append`ing to `node.alloc` appends to every node, that mean that every `alloc` in your network is literally the same object. You're making copied of references instead of value copies of that object somewhere.

Comment: I don't use the old syntax of `namedtuple`, but `defaults=[[]]` is giving every `Node` the exact same list when defaulting. You should *never* have a default argument to a function be mutable, and that applies to cases like this as well.

Comment: So, if that comes from the default parameter of Node object, I should build every Node with an explicit empty alloc atribute ? a = Node('a', 10) becomes a = Node('a', 10, [ ]) ?

Comment: Yes. `dataclass`es allow for a default factory argument that generates new default arguments as needed to solve this issue, but named tuples don't have that capability afaik unfortunately (likely because it's a bit unusual to hold mutable objects like lists in immutable objects like named tuples, so that capability is unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Carcigenicate ! It works as intended now, I mean this part does, I still got work to do. Take care ;)

Comment: No problem. I'd change `Graph` too  though by getting rid of the `default` argument. That'll bite you at some point too for the same reason later-on if you ever decide to make use of the default argument, and make two Graphs at some point. `default` arguments should really only ever be immutable.

Comment: I will work on that ;) Thank you so much !